# data sorting via primary key in jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have displayed data in view page using data table. I want to display data in descending order according to

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.BusinessRegModel.OrderByDescending(v => v.BusinessId).ToList());

        }
```

`BusinessId` is primary key.

But in view page, data is not sorted via primary key. I am using jquery data table to display data.

```
<table id="tblBusinessData" class="table" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Edit/Print</th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegNum)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NameOfFirm)
            </th>
            //code blocks
             </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BusinessId }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Print", "Details", new { id = item.BusinessId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
            </td>
            //code blocks
```

But the data is not sorted in descending order via BusinessId key. How can I do this? I need to display data in descending order by BusinessId.

jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#tblBusinessData').DataTable();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the column Id to the HTML and hide it via configuration:

```
$('#tblBusinessData').DataTable({
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": [0],
    "visible": false
  }],
  "order": [
    [0, "desc"]
  ]
});
```

Comment: That can really mess up some stuff, trust me, I know...

Comment: Such as? I've used Data Tables countless times and never had a problem with sorting or visibility.

Comment: I actually use it like this all the time, but I'm also aware of all that might happen because of this, a simple example is when exporting the table, the hidden column goes into the exported file, the simple fix is to apply a selector for excluding `:eq(0)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to set the desired order in your data before you send it to DataTables, you can simply set `order: []` to disable the initial sort while still being able to click on the column headers.

```js
$('#tblBusinessData').DataTable({
    order: []
});
```